# How to use function find('list') get data from other table beside its model?

Tags: cakephp

I am new of Cakephp I stuck by using function find('list') to get data from other table inside User model. Example i have User Model want get List of group andgroup has table "groups" but i don't want create php files for group controller and group model.

```
    <?php
      //User model
       class User extends AppModel {

         public function getGroupList() {
            /* Here i want return list all group by use function find('list') 
             * but group has table name "groups" and i don't want use sql query string.
             * Note that group i don't create  files php in controller and model.
             */

         }

       } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to create a groups controller?  Doing things cakes way will often make your life easier.

There will be an extra sql query (or join at least) involved in either case.

Comment: I have other reason that need to do that way, as my wanted does any good solution?

Comment: Without knowing more, I don't think I can help much more than pointing out the [MySQL Join documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).